# Extjs 4 MVC TabPanel - bad rendering tab

Tags: extjs

Please, help me. I am creating a TabPanel using the MVC. At the time of rendering panel add tab. Here is the code of the two views and controller. The result is a distorted picture. 
The title of the tab is drawn twice: at the top and bottom (stretched to full screen). When I change in the controller function addNewTab() the line  "***tp.add({xtype: 'mytab'}).show();***" 
to the other "***tp.add({title: 'new Tab', html: 'MVC New Tab Example'}).show();***", then everything is rendered properly. I will be grateful for the help.

```
Views:
Ext.define('MY.view.Tab', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Tab',
    alias: 'widget.mytab',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.title = 'new Tab';
        this.html = 'MVC New Tab Example';
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

Ext.define('MY.view.TabPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.mytabpanel',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.id = 'MYTabPanel';
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});


Controller:
Ext.define('MY.controller.TabPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    requires: ['MY.view.Tab'],
    init: function() {
        this.control({
            '#MYTabPanel': {
                render: this.addNewTab
            }
        });
    },
    addNewTab: function(tp) {
        tp.add({xtype: 'mytab'}).show();  //it work bad
        //tp.add({title: 'new Tab', html: 'MVC New Tab Example'}).show();  //it work good
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `mytab` class extends `Ext.tab.Tab`. That means that this code `tp.add({xtype: 'mytab'});`
is adding a `Tab` as a main view for the `TabPanel`. A tab is created automatically for every panel or container you add to the tab panel and consists of just the button-like component at the top of the view.

That means that when you call the code above, a `Tab` is created and pushed into the `TabPanel` as a view, then the `TabPanel` creates another another `Tab` using the same title and attaches it to the top of the `Tab` you just added.

This code `tp.add({title: 'new Tab', html: 'MVC New Tab Example'})'` works because you are actually adding a `panel` (The default `xtype` used by Ext is panel) and the `TabPanel` is creating the tab for you using the title you've provided.

To fix: make `MY.view.Tab` extend `Panel` instead of `Tab`. If you're trying to customize just the tab for a particular view, dig into the source for `Ext.tab.Panel` and check out the undocumented `tagConfig` property that you can add to `TabPanel` items.

Comment: Yes, I realized my mistake! Thank you very much for your help!